# If a sorcerer knows the Mage Hand cantrip and then takes the Telekinetic feat, how does that interact with the Metamagic option Distant Spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, sorcerer, metamagic

Say a sorcerer already knows the *mage hand* cantrip, and then takes the Telekinetic feat. If they cast *mage hand* and apply the Metamagic option Distant Spell to it, what would its range be?
(Ignore the fact that, by RAW, the hand disappears if it's ever more than 30 feet from the caster.)

The description of the [Metamagic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#Metamagic-372) option Distant Spell says:

> When you cast a spell that has a range of 5 feet or greater, you can spend 1 sorcery point to double the range of the spell.

The second benefit of the [Telekinetic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/telekinetic) feat says (TCoE, p. 81):

> You learn the *mage hand* cantrip. [...] If you already know this spell, its range increases by 30 feet when you cast it.

Both effects apply "when you cast".

What is the range of the *mage hand* spell if the Telekinetic sorcerer uses Distant Spell when they cast it?
Is it **90 feet** ((2 × 30) + 30)?
Or is it **120 feet** (2 × (30 + 30))?

Is there anything RAW about ordering effects with the same trigger, or is it just DM fiat?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The new range is 120 feet

The Telekinetic feat changes the way you cast *mage hand* if you already had the spell. Effectively, it rewrites the spell specifications for the caster so that you have a 60-foot range for the spell instead of 30 feet.

Distant Spell is a modifier that can applied on top of a spell that you cast. It will be applied to the "new and improved" version of *mage hand* that the caster has.

Comment: That's how I would rule it as a DM, but I'm getting hung up on both of the features using the "when you cast it" wording. One always happens when you cast it, and the other can optionally happen when you cast it, but there's nothing saying which goes first. Also, the choice for Telekinetic to add 30 instead of doubling stands out as deliberate.

Comment: @JustinAnderson XGtE:p77 "If two or more things happen at the same time [...] the person [...] who controls that creature decides the order in which those things happen."

Comment: @SilentAxe That's a optional rule from xanathars. Other tables may do other things.

Comment: @SilentAxe That may end up being the only possible RAW answer to this question, that it's up to the DM unless the party's using that optional rule on simultaneous effects from Xanathar's, in which case it's up to the caster.

Comment: Since the question doesn't quite specify that _only_ RAW should be considered, I'd say this answer can be further supported by reasoning from Rules as Fun. When in doubt, a DM should pick the rules interpretation that respects players' character build choices and allows them to make maximal use of their abilities. Consider, after all, the better feats this player had to forego in favor of taking Telekinetic.

Comment: I think the reason for the oddness of one adding 30 while the other doubles is to avoid anyone thinking that two effects wouldn't stack, per the rule on [Combining Game Effects](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DMG-Errata.pdf) (DMG, p. 252). I think this answer isn't complete without these comments about simultaneous and combining effects, but I'll accept it.